# Lagrange's theorem proof

Tags: group-theory

I read the answers to these questions:

[Proof of Lagrange theorem - Order of a subgroup divides order of the group](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/267279/proof-of-lagrange-theorem-order-of-a-subgroup-divides-order-of-the-group)

[Lagrange's theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/16802/lagranges-theorem)

How do I know that the cosets of H have the same number of elements?(That equivalence classes form a partition of G.)

Answer (score 2):

Consider a function defined by $f:H\to Ha$ by $f(x)=xa.$ Then it can be easily verified that $f$ is bijection. i.e., $H$ and $Ha $ has same cardinality.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Consider the map $H\to gH$ given by $h\mapsto gh$. Prove that it is bijective.

Answer (score 0):

Let $a$ and $b$ be any two elements, $H$ a finite subgroup. Consider $aH$ and $bH$. If $|aH|\neq|bH|$ then there must be two elements in $H$, say $f$ and $g$ such that either $af=ah$ or $bf=bh$. Assume WLOG $af=ah$. Then $f=h$, a contradiction. Thus all the coasts have the same size.